# Migrating JSF Version Error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, jsf-1.2

Im trying migrate from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0.

I have a little problem. When I start the Tomcat server, it returned the next error:

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandle"

I have read about this error, and I have changed some lines in my web.xml, but the problem not disappear.

Here is my complete web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>grp2</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <description>
     This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
     the rendered HTML output.
     If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript   code
     that submits the corresponding form.
     If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested   parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'
   </description>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <description>
     If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
     former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
     with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
     if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
     Default is 'false'
 </description>
 <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <description>
        If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able
        to restore the former vertical scroll on every request.
        Convenient feature if you have pages with long lists and you
        do not want the browser page to always jump to the top if
        you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same
        page. Default: &quot;false&quot;
     </description>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>descargas.ficheros.dir</param-name>
  <param-value>I:/RECURSOS/biblos/ficheros</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>resource.properties.name</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>fichero.pdf.dir</param-name>
  <param-value>I:/RECURSOS/biblos/ficheros</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
        com.tratecnica.sep.grp.web.filter.LoginFilter
  </filter-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>login_page</param-name>
    <param-value>/index.jsp</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/grp/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/file/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LogInitiator</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.tratecnica.sep.webextensions.servlet.LogInitiator</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>log4j.config.file</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/grp.log4j.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-  class>com.tratecnica.sep.grp.file.servlet.DownloadFileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/file/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>pdfViewerServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.tratecnica.sep.grp.file.servlet.PdfViewerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>pdfViewerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/filePDF/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>GuiServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
        com.tratecnica.sep.grp.web.servlet.GuiServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>GuiServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/GuiServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/grp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
 <exception-type>
        com.tratecnica.sep.grp.web.ControllerException
 </exception-type>
 <location>/grp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>
        com.tratecnica.sep.grp.data.exception.DataException
  </exception-type>
  <location>/grp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
   <exception-type>
        com.tratecnica.sep.crypto.exception.CryptoException
   </exception-type>
   <location>/grp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
  <location>/grp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have always worked with an only JSF version. I have never changed the JSF version. I dont know where is the error.

I need your help.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Are you converting same project to JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0?

Comment: Follow Facelets 1.x to 2.x migration instructions in that duplicate.

Comment: if you are migrating from1.2 to 2.0 then check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0